# Повторные AJAX запросы JQ-JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Суть такова, к примеру есть функция которая делает запрос на сервер для генерации ссылки по последующим запуском этой ссылки в плеере. Ну есть одна проблемка к примеру на сайте в блоке есть плейлист и кнопки в плеере, когда человек быстро клацает эти кнопки вперёд назад или плейлист то генерируется очень много запросов.. и они как то становятся в очередь или что? к примеру в плейлисте 10 названий, он быстро клацнул на все, не дожидаясь ответа от сервера.. к примеру остановился на 10.когда запрос завершился скрипт включает этот фаил к примеру 10 раз... я сделал переменную для ajax запроса и выставил флаги к в примере в низу, по 10 раз файл перестал запускаться. но всё равно запросы проскакивают если быстро переключатся между файлами... как бы это так решить мм? блокировать интерфейс или кнопки до загрузки файла не вариант) надо как то сделать если он быстро переключает то скрипт загружает только последний выбранный файл )

```
 resetnumber = 0;
go = true;
//Генерация ссылки
function player(idurl) {

  if (go == true) {
    go = false;
    ajax = $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "http://site.ru&sesid=" + coocike + "&hd=720&id=" + idurl,
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {

        if (XMLHttpRequest.statusText != "abort") {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://site.ru&sesid=' + coocike,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 5000,
            error: function() {
              alert('не авторизован к примеру');
              window.location.href = '/error';
            },
            success: function() {
              go = true;
              alert('БЫЛА ОШИБКА переподключаемся');
              player(idurl);
              resetnumber++;
              $('.infoerr').html('Возможно проблемы с интернетом переподключаемся' + resetnumber);
            }
          });
        }
      },

      success: function(json) {
        go = true;
        resetnumber = 0;
        file = json.get.file;
        RUN(file); //включаем плеер
        $('#preload').stop().fadeOut();

        setInterval(function() {
          subtitrs(json.get.subtitrs); //Запускаем субтитры например
        }, 100);

      }
    })

  } else {
    ajax.abort();
    go = true;
    player(idurl);


  }
}
```

Comment: может сделать если go = false то titmeout 1000  player(idurl); к примеру?  и после повторно запуска player(idurl) делаем cleartimeout но такое ощущение что это всё станет в очередь и он запустится 100500 раз

Answer (score 1):

Перед запросом

```
ajax = $.ajax({
```

сделайте "unbind" для кнопки (если JQuery), а в коллбеке ответа

```
success: function(json) { вот здесь }
```

обратное назначение

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){ ... })
```

В этом случае скрипт не будет реагировать на многократные нажатия, пока не вернется ответ сервера.

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, так как инициализация проходит по многим фактором, кнопки в плеере, блок с плейлистом, кнопки вперёд назад в браузере, и при загрузке страницы скрипт проверяет hash урла. если он будет быстро клацать браузерные кнопки наз к примеру ?и тем более если он клацает на новое что то из плейлиста в определённых блоках обновляется инфа, постеры и тд..  там всё между собой переплетено что ппц...  надо как то внутри этой функции нашаманить

Comment: var filterTimer,
 timeout = 0;
send = true; if(send == true){ timeout = 0 } else {timeout = 1000} 
    clearTimeout(filterTimer);
    filterTimer = setTimeout(function(){send = false;
        $.ajax({success: function(json) {send = true }});
    }, timeout);

Comment: Смею предположить, что у Вас нет пользовательского сценария. В этом случае полагаю нужно определиться что, как и в какой последовательности пользователь может нажимать. Когда и как плеер реагирует на действия пользователя. Тогда станет предельно понятно как реализовать вашу задачу. Попробуйте такой подход.

Comment: в общем такая ситуация) если он первый раз запускает плеер то запускается без задержек каких либо.. если всё ок получаем к примеру инфу в переменную что файл получен..  далее если он переключил файл в плейлисте опять без задержек.. но если он быстро переключает нужна задержка к примеру в 1 секунду перед тем как ajax отправит запрос за файлом

Comment: может создать переменную с отсчётом к примеру 3 секунды? и если он переключает быстрее чем отсчёт прошёл то делаем задержку, а если ajax уже сделал запрос и получил файл, то переменную с отсчётом ставим на 0??

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать так, по простому. Лажовая конечно идея, но на первый случай пойдёт) дело в том что там ещё идёт Ajax запрос на остановку, так бы я вообще не парился.

```
timeout = 0;  
    function zz(){
        if(typeof ajax !== 'undefined'){
        ajax.abort();
        }
        timeout = timeout;
        clearTimeout(filterTimer); 
        filterTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        timeout = 1500;
        ajax = $.ajax({
        ...
          success: function(jsondata) { 
        timeout = 300;
        }
        })
        }
```